# How to create a AWS lambda package using python?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have created the lambda function by using inline code editor for video convert process using zencoder its worked fine.

Now i have to Resize the images in 3 different sizes and from one bucket to another bucket.

For this scenario i need to import some python modules. But it says error like no module found image .

This was my lambda code.

```
import boto3
import cStringIO
import urllib
import os
import image
fp=urllib.urlopen('iamgeurl')
img = cStringIO.StringIO(fp.read())
im = Image.open(img)
im2 = im.resize((500, 100), Image.NEAREST)  
out_im2 = cStringIO.StringIO()
im2.save(out_im2, 'PNG')
conn = boto.connect_s3()
b = conn.get_bucket('Bucketname')
k = b.new_key('example.png')  
k.set_contents_from_string(out_im2.getvalue())
```

Answer (score 7):

First of all, export your code from the lambda dashboard. Then do the following:

Unzip the downloaded package into a directory, for example project-dir.

Install any libraries using pip. Again, you install these libraries at the root level of the directory.

```
pip install module-name -t /path/to/project-dir
```

Zip the content of the project-dir directory, which is your deployment package.

Zip the directory content, not the directory. The contents of the Zip file are available as the current working directory of the Lambda function. For example: `/project-dir/codefile.py/lib/yourlibraries`

Upload the zip file back to your lambda function.

For more information: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html

Comment: Thanks, It worked. Just for information, could you please elaborate why it was not working when I zipped the folder?

Comment: AWS Lambda requires you to zip just the content. Step 4 on this doc from aws: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html

Comment: Can we do that and still be able to modify the code inline? It seems that after adding a number of libraries, the zip file is large and it doesn't allow me to update the code inline anymore (th code itself is not large). Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

To build the zip with your dependencies and your source file, I'm using a library I created for this specific use case called [juniper](https://github.com/eabglobal/juniper).

With a very simple manifest, you can easily create the zip artifact that you need to enter either in the console or through the awscli.

In your case if you have a requirements.txt with `image==1.5.27`, or whatever version you want. With this manifest:

```
functions:
  converter:
    requirements: ./src/requirements.txt.
    include:
    - ./src/lambda_function.py
```

After running `juni build`, you will have a **converter.zip** file with the image dependency included.